# Convert image pixel data to one big string

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am looking to take an input of an image then look through every pixel and see which of 60 colors in a tuple(which each have a character corresponding to it) it is closest to, then add that character of the color to a string.

```
#rgb values of each color with the character it is

RecRoomColors = [
    (191, 74, 84, 'a'),
    (179, 24, 45, 'b'),
    (107, 11, 38, 'c'),
    (113, 42, 56, 'd'),
    (115, 60, 55, 'e'),
    (169, 51, 39, 'f'),
    (198, 86, 46, 'g'),
    (195, 119, 81, 'h'),
    (199, 184, 101, 'i'),
    (200, 175, 46, 'j'),
    (161, 92, 37, 'k'),
    (119, 89, 61, 'l')
    (59, 74, 51, 'm'),
    (40, 70, 36, 'n'),
    (99, 148, 43, 'o'),
    (127, 159, 83, 'p'),
    (96, 168, 118, 'q'),
    (16, 93, 47, 'r'),
    (4, 54, 42, 's'),
    (43, 69, 60, 't'),
    (46, 79, 84, 'u'),
    (3, 74, 74, 'v'),
    (13, 143, 133, 'w'),
    (98, 187, 183, 'x'),
    (96, 175, 200, 'y'),
    (19, 156, 200, 'z'),
    (6, 80, 114, '`'),
    (45, 84, 105, '~'),
    (44, 73, 117, '!'),
    (4, 52, 124, '@'),
    (25, 99, 194, '#'),
    (96, 148, 206, '$'),
    (148, 125, 205, '%'),
    (74, 25, 191, '^'),
    (43, 19, 117, '&'),
    (79, 66, 118, '*'),
    (81, 55, 92, '('),
    (57, 24, 75, ')'),
    (111, 60, 127, '_'),
    (188, 137, 204, '-'),
    (192, 111, 163, '+'),
    (192, 42, 79, '='),
    (119, 12, 68, '['),
    (95, 49, 78, ']'),
    (30, 17, 37, '{'),
    (55, 27, 39, '}'),
    (63, 38, 44, '¼'),
    (115, 59, 44, '|'),
    (172, 123, 91, ';'),
    (130, 93, 75, ':'),
    (82, 58, 58, '9'),
    (34, 27, 43, '"'),
    (113, 111, 116, '<'),
    (140, 137, 141, '>'),
    (167, 167, 169, ','),
    (199, 199, 199, '.'),
    (91, 94, 101, '?'),
    (67, 70, 79, '/'),
    (39, 42, 59, '1'),
    (18, 20, 41, '2'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary where its keys will be the pixels and the values the characters. Your code would be:

```
RecRoomColors = {
    (191, 74, 84): 'a',
    (179, 24, 45): 'b',
    (107, 11, 38): 'c',
    ... # you have to complete here the rest of the values
    (18, 20, 41): '2',
}
```